# Difference between 3 campy 80mm deep section wheels

Tags: wheels, campagnolo

Currently, three 80mm wheels are listed in Campagnolo's websites, but I can't fully see what's exactly the difference between them.

1. BORA ULTRA 80
2. BULLET ULTRA 80MM
3. BULLET 80MM

I guess BULLET 80MM is a cheaper version of BULLET ULTRA 80MM (using aluminium in places or what else), but no clue between the first two.  So, while I've not made the hardest research ever, very little (or even no) info available on the comparison of them.

Comment: Can you see what weights they are? Or maybe different hubs? Or rim material? Any of these might give a better idea of the differences. Rim depth is just one descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The najor difference is that Bora wheels are full carbon while Bullet are both aluminium rims with carbon profile. Also Bora wheels are tubular and Bullet are clincher rims. Still Bora are considerably lighter. And they have carbon hub bodies.

As for these 2 Bullet models, as you said Ultra are slightly lighter; not sure where the weight savings come from though...

Answer (score 2):

```
BORA ULTRA 80
BULLET ULTRA 80MM
BULLET 80MM
```

This question in part relates to Campagnolo nomenclature that extends across the wheel range.

Where a wheel is described as "Ultra" you will find a carbon hub body with alloy flanges bonded on, and an open bearing system. The bearing system may be ceramic-on-steel running in a grease bath (called USB) or may be ceramic-on-stainless steel (called CULT). The Bullet 80 Ultra is available in both versions, the Bora 80 Ultra only in the CULT version.

Non-Ultra wheels have an all-alloy hub and runs on sealed cartridge bearings which have a higher pre-load, and therefore more rolling resistance than their "open" counterparts. The wheel is also heavier as the cartridge bearings and the alloy hub shell weigh more than their Ultra counterparts. They are, though, less expensive.

There is a difference in the tyres that these wheels are designed for, in that Bora are designed for tubular tyres which are bonded to the rim, wheras Bullet in both "normal" and "Ultra" format are designed for clincher-type tyres which fit like "normal" cycle tyres.

Unless you are racing at elite level, tubular tyres, although generally felt to offer better roadholding and to be "faster" are probably a complication that you neither want nor need. If a tubulat tyre punctues, in practical terms,